# Get a List of results where items != already existing items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am developing an asp.net application and I have the following list:

```
public static List<SelectedSongKey_List> SelectedSongKeys(int songId)
{
    var db = new BMDWorshipEntities();
    var results = (from x in db.Keys
                   where x.SongId == songId
                   select x.ChordKey).ToList();

    var sortingOrder = new List<string>()
    {
        "Ab", "A", "Bb", "B", "C", "C#", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "F#", "Gb", "G"
    };

    results = results.OrderBy(x => sortingOrder.IndexOf(x)).ToList();

    var skList = new List<SelectedSongKey_List>();
    foreach(var sk in results)
    {
        skList.Add(new SelectedSongKey_List()
        {
            SongKey = sk.Trim()
        }); 
    }

    return skList;
}
```

This list will populate a drop-down list with all the existing `ChordKeys`:

Now I would like to make another List containing all the ChordKeys (Chords are in the `sortingOrder`) that don't exist on the db yet.

What `results` statement can I write in order to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *What results statement can I write in order to do that*? Does `sortingOrder` contain all your keys?

Comment: Yes, I need a results query containing all keys (listed in sortingOrder) minus the keys that already exist on the db that I'm querying from.

Comment: And `results` is also of type `string`?

Comment: results is a list of strings yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Except Clause

```
var exceptedList = sortingOrder.Except(results).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the `sortingOrder` and keep only items not already in results.

```
    var notInDb = sortingOrder.Where(item => !results.Contains(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda `Where` statement on `sortingOrder` to return only those values not contained in `results`:

```
var newChords = sortingOrder.Where(c => return !results.Contains(c));
```

EDIT: will leave this here for posterity, but [Richa Garg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39266792/4546999) is easier to read.